# pandas calling an element from imported data

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file with dates.

```
import pandas as pd 
spam=pd.read_csv('DATA.csv', parse_dates=[0], usecols=[0], header=None)
spam.shape
```

is (n,1)

How can I call an element as I do in Numpy (ex. I have an array A.shape => (n,1), if I call A[5,1] I get the element on the 5th row in the 1st column) ?

Comment: read the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numpy arrays index at zero, so you'll actually need A[4,0] to get the element on the 5th row of the 1st column.

But this is how you'd get the same as Numpy Arrays.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2)) # create a 2 by 2 DataFrame object
>>> df.ix[1,1]
-1.206712609725652
>>> df
          0         1
0 -0.281467  1.124922
1  0.580617 -1.206713
```

`iloc` is for integers only, whereas `ix` will work for both integers and labels, and is available in older versions of Pandas.

```
>>> df.iloc[1,1]
-1.206712609725652
```